# Export Warning async task in for loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, autodesk, revit-api

I have the method here http://teocomi.com/export-revit-warnings-list-from-api/ and am calling it from an application macro method to export warnings for a folder of rvt files:

```
public async void ExportWarningHTML()
{
    Autodesk.Revit.UI.UIApplication uiapp = this;
    Document doc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

    // Input Directory
    string inputDir = @"C:\input";

    // Output Directory
    string outputDir = @"C:\output";

    //Get files from inputDir
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(inputDir, "*.rvt");

    // Set open options to detach from central and preserve ws
    OpenOptions openOptions = new OpenOptions();
    openOptions.DetachFromCentralOption = DetachFromCentralOption.DetachAndPreserveWorksets;

    // Process each *.rvt file in folder
    // Naive approach. DOES NOT WORK.           
    foreach(string file in files)
    {           
        // Get current doc
        var docLast = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

        // Open new document
        var docNext = ActiveUIDocument.Application.OpenAndActivateDocument(file);

        // Close last document          
        docLast.Close(false);

        // Export Warnings
        var html = await Win32Api.ExportWarinings(uiapp, outputDir);    
    }   
}
```

}

However this only works for the first file then crashes. How can I modify this code or the linked "ExportWarnings" code I linked to to have this process a folder of .rvt files.

Comment: It looks like it's crashing because of the way you're opening and closing documents.  I may be wrong, this is just a hunch.  Try adding try catch and break points to see where it crashes.  Just guessing it would probably read best to read ```ActiveUIDocument.Application.OpenAndActivateDocument(file);  await Win32Api.ExportWarinings(uiapp, outputDir);  ActiveUIDocument.Application.Close(false);```  Possibly wrong but I don't see, from this code, any reason to do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations on your very nice solution to [Export Revit Warnings List From Api](http://teocomi.com/export-revit-warnings-list-from-api)!

As you know, the Revit API can only be used within a valid Revit API context. Such a context is provided only within callback functions provided by the Revit API, such as external command `Execute`. Furthermore, the Revit API is not multi-threading. Making calls to the API outside such a context can lead to a crash. That may well be exactly what you are experiencing.

Therefore, I wonder whether `async` can be used at all in this context. One possibility to handle these restrictions is by making use of external events:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.28

Is this code running in an external command `Execute` method? If so, how about just removing the `async` stuff, and simply calling `Sleep` repeatedly until Revit has finished processing the first file?

No, that will probably not work, and is probably not right at all.

Next suggestion: remove `async`; make the call to process the next file; when it is done, raise an external event; within the external event, repeat  the algorithm to process the next file; etc.

I am very much looking forward to hearing how you resolve this!

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! An honor to get a response from you. I was thinking along the same lines and I now have a solution using external events that works. I will post a more detailed follow up comment later. Your links to the event documentation helped set me straight. For the record the code I linked to in my question is not mine. Thank you.

Comment: my pleasure! thx for your appreciation! congratulations on solving! looking forward to a more detailed sample anon. if it is complete and generic enough to be of general interest, i would love to add it to the blog.